# CKEditor initial height

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I wanted to place a CKEditor 4 on a div and fill its content, then dynamically resize the editor if the window is resized. This works ok, but on instanceReady, the size of the editor is a default value of 200px, then I have to call my custom resize function to fit the div's size.

Is there a way to set the size of the editor to the div size, before showing it?.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>

  <style>
    html, body { 
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    header { 
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 50px;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 50px;
    }
    #content { 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
      box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
      padding-top: 50px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
      margin-bottom: -50px;
    } 
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>title etc</header>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <footer>copyright etc</etc>
  <script>
    function resize(editor){
      editor.resize($("#content").width(), $("#content").height());
    };

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt){
      alert("Editor size before resize: " + editor.ui.space( 'contents' ).getStyle( 'height' ));
      resize(evt.editor);
      alert("Editor size after resize: " + editor.ui.space( 'contents' ).getStyle( 'height' ));
    });

    $(window).resize(function() { resize(editor) });
    $(document).resize(function() { resize(editor) });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the initial height in the config:

```
config.height = 500;        // 500 pixels.
config.height = '25em';     // CSS length.
config.height = '300px';    // CSS length.
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-height

Or when you create the instance:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
    height: '500px'
});
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace

Comment: Yes Moob, I've tried that, but if I set height: $("#content").height() the editor's height is bigger than the content div height.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this. You asked how to set the initial height. You can do so in the config or upon initialising the instance. Your code shows you are already able to change the height on resize - are you saying that when you *do* change the height it is incorrect?